# How to use semi-transparent png images in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, png, transparency

How can I use semi-transparent png images in IE6?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact you can using [IE6 PNG Fix.](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) There are some limitations, but overall, it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have to say I prefer DD_belatedPNG over supersleight. It's way easier to implement and doesn't seem to deadlock IE6 plus hover works out of the box.

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the AlphaImageLoader transform can [deadlock IE6](http://blogs.cozi.com/tech/2008/03/transparent-pngs-can-deadlock-ie6.html).

Use [PNG8s](http://blogs.cozi.com/tech/2008/03/transparent-pngs-can-deadlock-ie6.html) instead of regular PNG32s. You are restricted to 256 colors and 1 bit of alpha transparency, but it beats randomly deadlocking the browser.

Comment: You can actually have 8 bits of alpha transparency in a PNG8 image, but IE6 will only render completely transparent or completely opaque. Other browsers render the 8-bit transparency just fine.

Comment: True, the PNG8 format has 256 levels of transparency, but as far as IE6 is concerned, it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue once about png transparency in ie6 and what saved me was this:

http://allinthehead.com/retro/338/supersleight-jquery-plugin

hope it help

Answer (score -1):

You can't... IE6 doesn't support transparent PNGs.  Your best option is to use transparent GIFs and format them to match the background they go over.

Edit: On that note: http://ie6update.com/

Comment: What it actually doesn't support is semi-transparent (or: translucent) PNG.