# Transparent background png image issue in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, png-24

background image of type PNG is not transparent in ie6

Answer (score 3):

See these posts

[IE6 PNG transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697682/ie6-png-transparency)

[How to use semi-transparent png images in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832752/how-to-use-semi-transparent-png-images-in-ie6)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in IE6: Transparent PNGs are only supported [with some hacks](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6).

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-know bug. There are several workarounds, e.g. you can try using Google's [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) library.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should definitely check the JQuery plugin called Supersleight, created by the guys on All In The Head &  24 Ways. They fixed some problems that comes with using AlphaImageLoader on IE6. From the 24 Ways page:

- Works with both inline and background images, replacing the need for both sleight and bgsleight
- Will automatically apply position: relative to links and form fields if they don’t already have position set. (Can be disabled.)
- Can be run on the entire document, or just a selected part where you know the PNGs are. This is better for performance.
- Detects background images set to no-repeat and sets the scaleMode to crop rather than scale.

The last one is the most important! Here are the links:

- http://allinthehead.com/retro/338/supersleight-jquery-plugin
- http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue once about png transparency in ie6 and what saved me was this:

http://allinthehead.com/retro/338/supersleight-jquery-plugin

hope it help.