# What is the best way to save a PNG image with alpha transparency for IE6?

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-6, png, alpha-transparency

I am trying to save a 1 or 8-bit PNG image that looks nice in IE6.

Do you have any suggestions?

I have used Fireworks before, and that works pretty well, but I'm looking for other options.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IE 6 doesn't like PNG Transparencies as far as I remember.

There are lots of solutions, search for it or check out this other [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832752/how-to-use-semi-transparent-png-images-in-ie6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pngquant` or `pngnq` instead of Fireworks (these are command-line tools that convert 24-bit PNG to PNG8+alpha, which work decently in IE6).

If you're on OS X, then you can use [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com). It has "IE6-friendly alpha" option which tweaks alpha channel for more graceful degradation in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Try Paint.Net? You can choose Transparency-Level and Bitrate at "Save". http://www.paint.net/

I guess Gimp would be a choice too.

Comment: This forum http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=29151 post mostly demonstrates how to do it in Paint.NET

Answer (score 0):

IE6 doesn't support alpha-layer transparency.  Try saving it as a .gif instead, and/or using IE6 specific stylesheets.