# PNG image file display issue in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i have a problem in display the Png file in IE. It's work fine in Firefox and other browsers but the PNG file is display some kind of shadow in IE. Is there any solution to fix this problem. I have used this css code to fix this problem but still no hope.I would appreciate any help. Please..

```
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="+imagePath+")"
```

Comment: Which version of IE? Is the PNG a transparent one?

Comment: The shadow you see is most likely a semi-transparent part of the image that doesn't render properly on IE6. the css style you have should work if you put it on a div.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832752/how-to-use-semi-transparent-png-images-in-ie6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [JavaScript fix](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/pnghowto.htm) for older IE versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="+imagePath+", sizingMethod="crop")"
zoom:1;
background-image:none;
```

Make sure it has layout and you disable the bg image, if any.